# How can I make a jQuery progress bar reset on mouse drag action?

Tags: jquery, events, carousel, slick.js

I have installed the Slick carousel on my site along with some code I found for a nice looking progress bar. However, although the progress bar resets when the 'previous' and 'next' buttons are clicked, it doesn't reset when the slider is dragged.

I have played around with the jQuery events, but can't find one suitable for click & drag.

My site is http://bp112.betapark.co.uk/ and here is the jQuery Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var time = 2;
  var $bar,
    $slick,
    isPause,
    tick,
    percentTime;

  $slick = $('.slider');
  $slick.slick({
    draggable: false,
    arrows: true,
    speed: 1200,
    adaptiveHeight: false
  });

  $bar = $('.slider-progress .progress');

  function startProgressbar() {
    resetProgressbar();
    percentTime = 0;
    isPause = false;
    tick = setInterval(interval, 30);
  }

  function interval() {
    if (isPause === false) {
      percentTime += 1 / (time + 0.1);
      $bar.css({
        width: percentTime + "%"
      });
      if (percentTime >= 100) {
        $slick.slick('slickNext');
        startProgressbar();
      }
    }
  }

  function resetProgressbar() {
    $bar.css({
      width: 0 + '%'
    });
    clearTimeout(tick);
  }

  startProgressbar();

  $('.slick-next, .slick-prev').click(function() {
    startProgressbar();
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use slick events. For exemple `beforeChange` or `afterChange` and put there your action, not on click: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

```
$slick.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  startProgressbar();
});
```

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
      var time = 2;
      var $bar,
        $slick,
        isPause,
        tick,
        percentTime;

      $slick = $('.regular');
      $slick.slick({
        draggable: true,
        arrows: true,
        speed: 1200,
        adaptiveHeight: false
      });

      $bar = $('.slider-progress .progress');

      function startProgressbar() {
        resetProgressbar();
        percentTime = 0;
        isPause = false;
        tick = setInterval(interval, 30);
      }

      function interval() {
        if (isPause === false) {
          percentTime += 1 / (time + 0.1);
          $bar.css({
            width: percentTime + "%"
          });
          if (percentTime >= 100) {
            $slick.slick('slickNext');
            startProgressbar();
          }
        }
      }

      function resetProgressbar() {
        $bar.css({
          width: 0 + '%'
        });
        clearTimeout(tick);
      }

      startProgressbar();

      $slick.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
        startProgressbar();
      });
      
});
```

```css
.slider-progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.slider-progress .progress {
  width: 0%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #E74C3C;
}



/* SLICK BASE CSS */
.slick-prev {
background: #DDD;
border: none;
border-radius: none;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
left: 0;
padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
z-index: 40;
content:"prev";
}

.slick-next {
background: #DDD;
border: none;
border-radius: none;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
right: 0;
padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
z-index: 40;
}

html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
      color: black;
    }


    .slick-slide {
      transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
      opacity: .2;
    }
    
    .slick-active {
      opacity: .5;
    }

    .slick-current {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<section class="regular slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="slider-progress">        <div class="progress"></div>    </div>
```

**EDIT 1**

To stop on rollover use `pauseOnHover: true` on slick slider (the documentation rules: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/! ;) ) and work on very useful variable `isPause` to stop your bar:

```
$slick.on("mouseenter", function(){
   isPause = true;
}).on("mouseleave", function(){
   isPause = false;
})
```

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
      var time = 2;
      var $bar,
        $slick,
        isPause,
        tick,
        percentTime;

      $slick = $('.regular');
      $slick.slick({
        draggable: true,
        arrows: true,
        speed: 1200,
        adaptiveHeight: false,
        pauseOnHover: true /* add this option */
      });

      $bar = $('.slider-progress .progress');

      function startProgressbar() {
        resetProgressbar();
        percentTime = 0;
        isPause = false;
        tick = setInterval(interval, 30);
      }

      function interval() {
        if (isPause === false) {
          percentTime += 1 / (time + 0.1);
          $bar.css({
            width: percentTime + "%"
          });
          if (percentTime >= 100) {
            $slick.slick('slickNext');
            startProgressbar();
          }
        }
      }

      function resetProgressbar() {
        $bar.css({
          width: 0 + '%'
        });
        clearTimeout(tick);
      }

      startProgressbar();

      $slick.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
        startProgressbar();
      });

      $slick.on("mouseenter", function(){
        isPause = true;
      }).on("mouseleave", function(){
        isPause = false;
      })
      
});
```

```css
.slider-progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.slider-progress .progress {
  width: 0%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #E74C3C;
}



/* SLICK BASE CSS */
.slick-prev {
background: #DDD;
border: none;
border-radius: none;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
left: 0;
padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
z-index: 40;
content:"prev";
}

.slick-next {
background: #DDD;
border: none;
border-radius: none;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
right: 0;
padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
z-index: 40;
}

html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
      color: black;
    }


    .slick-slide {
      transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
      opacity: .2;
    }
    
    .slick-active {
      opacity: .5;
    }

    .slick-current {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<section class="regular slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="slider-progress">        <div class="progress"></div>    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry one last question - is there also anyway to make both the carousel and progress bar pause on hover? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer also for that. But Mikey, please, read the documentation! It is very helpful (for every plugin) and it is the first step that you have to do to look for help. Cheers. :)

Comment: Again, thank-you. I'm very new to jQuery and I did previously try adding 'pauseOnHover' which of course didn't work I as I missing the other part of the code. Many thanks again!!:)

Comment: You're welcome, Mikey. Fortunately SO also exists to help us! Cheers! ;)